# Alamofire formatting POST/PUT parameters swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have an issue using Alamofire on iOS (swift) :

When I try to send a request (in .POST or .PUT) with parameters like that :

```
parameters:["description": WhoGives, "images": (
    {
    container = offerImages;
    name = "563f993e4b00ddad7ed42790_0.jpg";
},
    {
    container = offerImages;
    name = "563f993e4b00ddad7ed42790_1.jpg";
}
)]
```

it results in a httpBody like this :

```
description="WhoGives"&images[][container]=“offerImages”&images[][name]=“563f993e4b00ddad7ed42790_0.jpg”&images[][container]=“ offerImages”&images[][name]=“563f993e4b00ddad7ed42790_1.jpg"
```

And I would like it to be :

```
description="WhoGives"&images[0][container]=“offerImages”&images[0][name]=“563f993e4b00ddad7ed42790_0.jpg”&images[1][container]=“ offerImages”&images[1][name]=“563f993e4b00ddad7ed42790_1.jpg"
```

As anyone found how to do it? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a `.Custom` parameter encoding to do this. Since there's no RFC spec published around collection URL encoding, Alamofire uses a common convention which works for many servers, but not all.

Here's a snippet from our `ParameterEncoding` docs.

> Since there is no published specification for how to encode collection types, the convention of appending `[]` to the key for array values (`foo[]=1&foo[]=2`), and appending the key surrounded by square brackets for nested dictionary values (`foo[bar]=baz`).

To implement this, you'll want to leverage the logic in the `encode` method for the `.URL` case along with the `queryComponents` method. You'll need to make a slight change to the `queryComponents` method to put the array index in the parameter value. Then you should be good to go.